# Recreating Dates in Sharepoint to show Workdays instead of Dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-calendar

I am creating a calendar in sharepoint based on workdays for my company. The way it works is: the first date i.e Oct 1 is Workday 1 unless it falls on a Saturday or Sunday and in that case, it would be the first Monday of the month. I am able to use calculated fields to determine the weekday but I am unable to change the layout of the calendar to show Workdays instead of dates.